# How to include javascript files when testing React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chai

I'm writing a test for a React component that uses the selectpicker javascript library.  Here's the Mount method:

```
componentDidMount() {
 const selectControl = $(this.refs.selectName);
 selectControl.selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

It works fine since I wrap the javascript created by webpack in a Rails environment that includes the selectpicker.js file in the assets, but the test I wrote doesn't know about this included file and throws the error:

> TypeError: selectControl.selectpicker is not a function

What is the best architecture here?  Should the component be including the javascript file?  Can I easily include the js file in my test?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to test exactly?

If you just want to test the rendering of your component without carrying if the selectpicker jQuery plugin has been applied, you can use a library like [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) (from Airbnb) that can do a shallow rendering without mounting your component

Comment: Thanks Michael, that might do the trick since none of the selectpicker logic is actually in the render.  I still wonder if I should add the javascript somehow to the component so this won't be an issue.